# Running DMA twice from server A to server B

Tags: sql-server, upgrade, sql-server-data-migration-assistant

is it possible to run DMA twice on the same destination server from the same source server in SQL server during migration to keep Target Server up to date with Source server ?

2nd DMA run will be done a week after 1st run .
Thank you for your help.